# C# DateTime.ToUniversalTime() in C++ Win32

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

I'm trying to identify the right type to use on my C++ (Win32) app that is receiving the return of an API call that returns a C# `DateTime.ToUniversalTime()` value.

So my question is:
Should I use a U64 to store the returned value from the c# function..or what would be the right C++ Type to use.

> > The client C++ environment is using
> >     Win32 + DirectX utilizing COM

No CLR, No WinRT, No CLI

Comment: Custom CLR host?  COM?  C++/CLI?  WinRT?  There is more than one way to interop with managed code, you have to be explicit.  Post a snippet.

Comment: Win32. DirectX utilizing COM - NO CLR, NO WinRT !!

Answer (score 1):

What does the API in question actually return? The `ToUniversalTime` method returns another `DateTime` object. If you want to use that with a Win32 API you would need to convert it to a `FILETIME` structure, something like this:

```
ULARGE_INTEGER uli;
uli.QuadPart = DateTime->ToFileTime();

FILETIME ft;
ft.dwLowDateTime = uli.LowPart;
ft.dwHighDateTime = uli.HighPart;
```

You could then convert the `FILETIME` to a `SYSTEMTIME` as normal:

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &st);
```

If the API method returns a `long long` or similar you can simply copy that into the `uli.QuadPart` field shown above.

Comment: FileTime is not a DateTime. I need to return a DateTime ....my clients are not JUST C++ apps. What am I missing ??

Comment: @SDDeveloper if the API is returning a .NET DateTime object then you have no choice but to use that object. This answer is merely giving you options for what to do with it once you have it.

Comment: @SDDeveloper: Your question implied you were getting a DateTime object in your Win32 app and wanted to know how to handle it. If that's not the question you're asking you'll need to provide more details.

Comment: The Cloud api returns a DateTime ..yes but the C++ does not have a datetime type so I need to find out what would be the type to use on the C++ side in order to get a datetime. The Cloud API is also used by IOS, Java, DotNet apps ...so I would rather stick to DateTime if I could ...

Comment: @JonathanPotter so is ULARGE_INTEGER the type that I should use on the C++ client in order to store and then manipulate a DateTime value returned by the API ??